# Pick 5 random letters from array

Tags: javascript

For school I need to make a script that prints 3 times something with 5 random letters. "ajshw kcmal idksj"

I have made this:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 
'z'];

var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
document.write('<br>' +  random);
```

But this only prints one letter. How can it print 5 letters 3 times?

Comment: Your `myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];` code is the key to get a random element from the array. You know functions? You could create a function that executes that code and then you could build another one to build a "word", which means running your random function 5 times. Then you can execute the "word" function 3 times and you're done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just making a nested loop:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
  'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y',
  'z'
];

const length = myArray.length;

const numStrings = 3;
const numLetters = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
  let string = "";

  for (let j = 0; j < numLetters; j++) {
    let letter = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)];
    string += letter;
  }
  console.log(string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate 5 times to generate each word with 5 letters and iterate 3 times to generate three words. You can use `for` loop to generate the words or you can use `array#map` to generate the words and using `array#join` you can join them.

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    random = [...Array(3)]
      .map(_ => [...Array(5)].map(_ => myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]).join(''))
      .join('<br>');
document.write(random);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to simply generate that single letter multiple times with a loop. A way to do this would go as follows:

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 
'z'];

var phrase = "";
for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        phrase = phrase + myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    }
    phrase = phrase + " ";
}
console.log(phrase)
```